# MySQL update a column's values to equal the sum of another column's values based on date and another column's value

Tags: mysql, loops

[image]

I took a screenshot of a portion of the table and added descriptors for what it is I am trying to do exactly. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi there, please look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  You did well in that you described what you want to achieve. but your question is more of a "please do this task for me". Madhur alreadyd guided your way. divide and conquer: first create a select query that calculates the values you want to use in your update statement and then use this as subquery for your update statement. If you do it in two steps, it is easier to solve and you don't ruin your database as easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`SUM()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) aggregation with `Group By` on `team` and `game_date`:

```
SELECT 
  team, 
  game_date, 
  SUM(minutes) AS team_minutes_played 
FROM 
  your_table_name 
GROUP BY 
  team, 
  game_date
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! It put me on the right path. I'm going to try to put those results into a temporary table to use to update those rows.